# Why don't people who get gastric bypass surgery starve to death?

Tags: diet, calories, meal, starvation

After a gastric bypass surgery you can only eat tiny meals, the severe calorie restriction causes rapid weight loss. What I don't understand is why the bodyweight will then eventually stabilize as the person would still be eating way less than what normal people eat?

Comment: What makes you think that people with gastric bypass cannot get enough calories to survive? Clearly they can. People starve to death below 500-800 calories, and run health risks at 1000-1200. A gp maintenance diet is 1300-1500. These numbers are from less than a minute's worth of googling.

Comment: @JimBalter Suppose I would have gotten extremely obese by overeating. I currently eat 3500 Kcal/day but I exercise a lot and I weight about 54 kg, so I would probably have to stop exercising (saves about 1000 Kcal/day) and eat more to start to gain weight. Eventually I'll become extremely obese, get a gastric bypass and then I'm restricted to, say, 1500 Kcal.I lose weight, but then I'll hit my current 54 kg at a BMI of 19 kg/m^2 and then what? Because without exercise I would currently need about 2500 Kcal/day...

Comment: "I would currently need about 2500 Kcal/day" -- obviously not.

Comment: @JimBalter [According to this website](http://www.runnersworld.com/tools/calories-burned-calculator) I burn slightly less than 800 Kcal per day. If I subtract 800 Kcal from my calorie intake of between 3500 and 4000 kcal a day then yields a calorie intake without exercise of between 2700 and 3200 Kcal/day. Now, it could be that I could eat less and the metabolic rate would adjust itself to that, but I don't see how I could eat just 1500 Kcal a day and not get severely  ill. 1500 Kcal is less than what I just had for dinner.

Comment: I had Sleeve Gastrectomy 10 months ago. I currently am able to eat only about 600-800 calories a day. During the first month I barely ate 300 calories a day. A lot of what have been said here is simply not true. I also wonder sometimes why we do not starve to death after the surgery, I do not have the answer but I can tell you that after the surgery your stomach is so small that you can fill it up with a few bites, the brain and stomach work together and esentially you feel full. In fact if you try to eat a little more you will vomit. Additionlly, in the process they remove the area of the sto